# Can I run Windows on a server?

Tags: windows, server, client, client-server, windows-server-2008

I want a Windows machine to act as a server, being able to open ports to clients and send data to them over the Internet.

Is it possible to install Windows on any server to act like it or should I purchase Windows Server?

I have never truly worked with servers before so I know my questions is silly. :) Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a normal windows on server computer and can do a lot of things with but if you have specific things to do, maybe you can try windows server and if it what you want, you can buy one ;)